# Размер кнопки не становить 0

Tags: unity3d

Мне нужно уменьшит кнопку корутиной до нуля, но почему-то она не становиться 0, а приблизительно 0.04-0.05

```
private IEnumerator reduceCloseButton(Vector3 fSize)
    {
        while(Mathf.Abs(closeButton.transform.localScale.y - fSize.y) >= 0.05f)
        {
            closeButton.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(closeButton.transform.localScale, fSize, 1 / 10f);
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        }
        closeButton.transform.localEulerAngles = fSize;
    }
```

в параметр передаю Vector3.zero

Comment: Какой тогда смысл отнимать, если  fSize.y == 0 всегда. Попробуй while(closeButton.transform.localScale.y  >= 0){...} closeButton.transform.localScale = fSize

Comment: @ValeraKvip так >= 0 будет всегда тру, т.к. данная конструкция никогда не достигнет нуля

Comment: Ну да,  в любом случае установи после цикла: closeButton.transform.localScale = Vector3.zero

Comment: @ValeraKvip цикл же никогда не завершиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так твой вариант работает.

```
private IEnumerator reduceCloseButton(Vector3 fSize)
{
    float duration = 50;
    float step = 1 / duration;
    float covDistance = 0;
    Vector3 startScale = closeButton.transform.localScale;
    while (covDistance < 1)
    {
        closeButton.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScale, fSize, covDistance);
        covDistance += step;
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
    }
    closeButton.transform.localScale = fSize;       
}
```

Мой вариант, уменьшать duration секунд.

```
private IEnumerator reduceCloseButton2(Vector3 fSize)
{
    float duration = 10;      
    float covDistance = 0;
    Vector3 startScale = closeButton.transform.localScale;
    while (covDistance < 1)
    {
         closeButton.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScale, fSize, covDistance);
         covDistance += Time.deltaTime / duration;          
         yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
    closeButton.transform.localScale = fSize;      
}
```

Почему не работал изначальный вариант:
<strike>Немного математики:</strike>  лучше не будем, и объясним примерно, но надеюсь верно
В твоем варианте ты всегда брал 9/10 от расстояния между текущим scale и 0. Представь что у тебя есть веревка и ты всегда отступаешь от нуля 9 частей и отрезаешь. В математике ты никогда не достигнешь нуля. В жизни да, а в программировании? Вероятно тоже нет. Твоя программа проработала у меня прилично минут и scale остановился на числе 5.605194E-45.

Я даже график начертил. scale == 1, x == time, y == scale.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем варианте я брал начальный scale, 0 и точки между ними  которая равно приближалась к ноль(и переискала его). 
График прямая
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему не работало с 0,05? Есть несколько гипотез: работало, но долго(scale очень большой или Fixedupdate изменен). Ты не все рассказал/показал.

Comment: спасибо, а все таки, есть предложения по поводу того почему мой варик не работал?

Comment: @k0vpack , Да, могу объяснить почему ноль не достигается, почему 0,05 нет, пока хз. Какое у тебя значение  localScale  для кнопки до вызова функции? И какое значение FixedUpdate? Возможно оно работало, просто через очень долгое время